# Mongoose.connection('once') what does it mean

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am newbie on MongoDb. What is the use of db.connect('once', function(){});

This will create the connection once per request??

This will by default close the connection when this job is done??

```
    mongoose.connect(uri, options);
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function(err, resp){
      console.log(resp);
    });
```

Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/

Answer (score 9):

when you use 'once' it signifies that the event will be called only once i.e the first time the event occurred like here in this case the first time when the connection is opened ,it will not occur once per request but rather once when the mongoose connection is made with the db

while the 'on' signifies the event will be called every time that it occurred

Answer (score 4):

It is the callback to be executed when the given event is generated. In your example to the function will be called when the connection to mongodb is open i.e. the connection is successful.

Comment: Is there any way to kill that specific connection which is running on port 27018. And My another parent connection i.e port 27017 will be stay connected to my project

Comment: @Abhay Hi, Abhay.  Are you on Linux?  I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I check my listening ports with> lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN.  For me, this returns: mongod  8865     root   12u  IPv6 128489      0t0  TCP *:28017 (LISTEN).  The ports are listed right before the (LISTEN) text at the very end of each line. The number listed immediately after the title is the PID and can be used to kill the process, If I wanted to kill above process I'd type> kill 8865.

Answer (score 1):

Here `db.on` it is kind of error handling you can use `then` and `catch`, And also `db.once` means the exactly like once that is to say once the connection is okay then do this for example `console.log`.